# monit: can't connect to the http interface

Tags: linux, iptables, http, monit

I'm setting up monit on a new site, which I'll refer to as mywebsite.com during this question.  I've set up the config to access monit's web interface page, but I can't connect to it.  I've got a basic firewall running with iptables, and I think I've made a hole for monit, but I can't connect to monit's web interface, and I don't know why.

I haven't set up anything to monitor yet:  my monit config looks like this:

```
## Start monit in the background (run as a daemon):
set daemon  120           # check services at 2-minute intervals

set httpd port 2812 and
  use address mywebsite.com  
  allow localhost      
  allow admin:password
```

I've restarted monit with these rules.

I've made a rule for monit in my iptables config, which looks like this:

```
#monit interface
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2812 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2812 -j ACCEPT
```

I've then imported these rules into `/sbin/iptables-restore`. I can see the monit entry when I do `sudo /sbin/iptables -L`:

```
...
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:2812 
...
```

But, when I go to `http://mywebsite.com:2812` i get `Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in the browser.

Any ideas, anyone?  I don't even know if the problem is anything to do with iptables.  Thanks in advance, Max

EDIT: I tried changing the 'localhost' line in the monit config thus:

```
set httpd port 2812 and
  use address mywebsite.com  
  allow mywebsite.com      
  allow admin:password
```

but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Seems you only allow localhost. You should allow your subnets.

Comment: thanks - see edit, is this what you meant by "allow your subnets"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To access Monit from outside nerwork, just set :

For no athentication and access from everywhere :

```
set httpd port 2812
```

For access from everywhere with authentication :

```
set httpd port 2812
   allow <auth_user>:<auth_password>
```

In your case, remove the `and` at the end of the line `set httpd port 2812 and`

**Note**: If you are testing the setup with password set as "password" you will receive this error:

```
Error: syntax error 'password'
```

Comment: that's worked - thanks!  The "and" part came from this site - http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-install-and-setup-monit-linux-process-and-services-monitoring-program/ - is that perhaps left over from an older version of monit, that had a different config syntax?

Comment: No, that is because in this tutorial they always deal with localhost. They don't explain how to access from outside localhost (look at the url in their print-screen)

Comment: This helped me a ton and I love monit

Comment: I suspect you have to specify at least one between the `allow` and `credentials` directives. See https://serverfault.com/a/900823/459872

Comment: just setting httpd port 2812 without allow does not work anymore. monit: monit httpd not started since no connections are allowed

Comment: If you have a firewall, dont forget to add an exception for that port. I had to run `ufw allow 2812` in order to get it working. after having the first line `set httpd port 2812 and` and the second line was `allow username:password`