# no httpd connection for monit started from systemd

Tags: ubuntu, monit

When starting `monit` my logs show that

```
[CET Oct 31 19:43:34] info     : Starting Monit 5.16 daemon
[CET Oct 31 19:43:34] error    : monit: monit httpd not started since no connect allowed
[CET Oct 31 19:43:34] info     : 'srv.home' Monit 5.16 started
```

despite having

```
set httpd port 2812
```

in `/etc/monit/monitrc`.

**Is there anything else needed to have the httpd server enabled when `monit` is started via systemd?**

Note: [A previous answer](https://serverfault.com/a/564603/78319) pointed to an extra `and`, which is not my case (the `and`was there, but an an introduction for following configuration lines, of which I believe I need none for an open, unauthenticated access. I also tried to add `and use address 10.10.10.254` to the line above expecting that this is the address the httpd monitor would bind to, unfortunately with the same effect)

Comment: I guess I've just hit the same issue. The question is old, but since I see no valid answer I've added mine.

Comment: nmap also shows NOTHING running on 2818 for me with this....

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/564574/monit-cant-connect-to-the-http-interface?noredirect=1&lq=1 <--- this got me running, but nmap still won't show anything open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have to specify at least one between the `allow` and `credentials` directives.

In my case I solved the issue simply adding the `ALLOW` directive

```
SET HTTPD PORT 2812
  USE ADDRESS 127.0.0.1
  ALLOW 127.0.0.1
```

See the [relevant code](https://github.com/arnaudsj/monit/blob/cc296bc9b53bcd916cd4228599c7cfc3be6913f6/http.c#L99) from monit sources.

Comment: Thanks Davide. I have forgotten about the question but thi s is an opportunity to review the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The monit http server is not responding until monit is fully started. It you specified an "start delay", the http server will not respond until that delay.
`set daemon 120 # check services at 2-minute intervals
 #   with start delay 240 # optional: delay the first check by 4-minutes but also responses from http server`